# Add new node to local XML file with JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'd like to add new elements to a XML file from a user input.
I've tried a lot possible ways but none of them worked for me :(

How can I add a new node/element/item to a existing local XML file using JavaScript or jQuery?

This is my current state:

```
function addElement() {
    var xml;
    if (window.activexobject) {
        xml = new activexobject("microsoft.xmlhttp");
    } else {
        xml = new xmlhttprequest();
    }
    xml.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xml.readystate == 4 && xml.status == 200) {
            var resp = xml.responsexml;
            var user = xml.responsexml.createelement("User");

            var name = xml.responsexml.createelement("name");
            name.appendchild(xml.responsexml.createtextnode("sof_user"));

            var admin = xml.responsexml.createelement("admin");
            admin.appendchild(xml.responsexml.createtextnode("false"));

            user.appendchild(name);
            user.appendchild(admin);
            xml.responsexml.documentelement.appendchild(user);
        }
    }
xml.open("get", "users.xml", true);
xml.send(null);
}
```

the XML should look like this:

```
<Users>
    <User>
        <name>testuser</name>
        <admin>true</admin>
    </User>
    <User>
        <name>sof_user</name>
        <admin>false</admin>
    </User>
    ....
</Users>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to save the file to the local hard drive from a browser?

Comment: @DanField Yes. And how to add a new token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to build up your XML something like this:

```
usersNode = document.createElement("Users");

userNode = document.createElement("User");
nameNode = document.createElement("name");
nameNode.innerText = "testuser";
adminNode = document.createElement("admin");
adminNode.innerText = "true";
userNode.appendChild(nameNode);
userNode.appendChild(adminNode);
usersNode.appendChild(userNode);

userNode = document.createElement("User");
nameNode = document.createElement("name");
nameNode.innerText = "sof_user";
adminNode = document.createElement("admin");
adminNode.innerText = "false";
userNode.appendChild(nameNode);
userNode.appendChild(adminNode);
usersNode.appendChild(userNode);

console.log(usersNode.innerHTML);
```

I think that should give you what you want.

Comment: How can I add these nodes to a existing XML file (users.xml)?

Comment: replace the `usersNode = document.createElement("Users");` with whatever your root node is.

Comment: Can you put together a JS fiddle or similar to demonstrate the issue you have?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have immediate access to the document, you can also get to it from an existing element:

```js
someElement.ownerDocument.createElement('User');
```